# How to cacluate the time variable and comapre a time data with the current time by python django?

Tags: python, django, time

For example, I have a model in models.py which looks like this:

```
class BlackList(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    flag1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    trytologintime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

And in the views.py, what I try to do is something like this:

```
......    
username = request.POST.get('username')  # Get username input first
password = request.POST.get('password')
user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
black_list_user = BlackList.objects.get(username=username)
# timenow = get time for now ( I do not know how to get it foe now )
passtime = timenow-black_list_user.trytologintime (Also do not know how to do the subtraction for time variable)
     if passtime > 24 hr (How to compare the time)
        black_list_user.flag1 = True
        black_list_user.save()
......
```

So, my main questions are:

1. how to get the current time?
2. how to do subtraction and compare two time variable?

Comment: [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Comment: @OlvinRoght Django datetime is not the same as python datetime. It is not this simple as Django by default stores timezone data in the datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can get the current time with `timezone.now()` where `timezone` is part of django.utils, if I recall correct.
2. For operations on dates, you can use `timedelta`, part of `datetime`

For instance, to move a date 24 hours into the future:

```
current_time = timezone.now()
tomorrow = current_time + timedelta(hours=24)
```

You can also compare dates as you would expect. So in your example:

```
last_login_time = disalloweduser.try_to_login_time
if last_login_time + timedelta(hours=24) > timezone.now():
    etc...
```